# how to show the ajax returned String in google table?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, google-visualization

This is my click event code in jsp

```
{
var tableList = makeAjaxCallToTable();
        alert("tableList.."+tableList);

        var obj = $.parseJSON(tableList); 
        tableData = new google.visualization.DataTable(obj);
        drawTable(tableData);
```

}

this is my ajax call

```
function makeAjaxCallToTable(){
        var returnVal;
        var selectedItem = piChart.getSelection()[0];
        if(selectedItem){
            var selectedItem = piChart.getSelection()[0];
             var selectedticketType = piData.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
             $.ajax({
                 type : 'GET',
                 url : 'incident_management_pichart_table.htm',
                 data : {
                     selectedticketType : selectedticketType,
                     selectedCIName : selectedCIName,
                 },
                 async : false,
                 success : function(responseText){
                     returnVal = responseText;
                },
                 error : function(e){
                     alert("An error occured: " + e.status + " " + e.statusText);
                        returnVal = '';
                 }
             });
        }
        alert('Here in ajax');

        return returnVal;
    }
```

this ajax ill give reslt as string like following

> [["ENVCOFWINTELPROD","Resolved","Interaction","Chennai","incident","2015-06-10 00:00:00.0","null"],["ENVCOFWINTELPROD","Resolved","Interaction","Chennai","incident","2015-06-10 00:00:00.0","null"],["ENVCOFWINTELPROD","Resolved","Interaction","Chennai","incident","2015-06-10 00:00:00.0","null"],["ENVCOFWINTELPROD","Resolved","Interaction","Chennai","incident","2015-06-10 00:00:00.0","null"],["ENVCOFWINTELPROD","Resolved","Interaction","Chennai","incident","2015-06-10 00:00:00.0","null"],["ENVCOFWINTELPROD","Resolved","Interaction","Chennai","incident","2015-06-10 00:00:00.0","null"],["ENVCOFWINTELPROD","Resolved","Interaction","Chennai","incident","2015-06-10 00:00:00.0","null"]]

using google charts am creating table by the following code

```
function drawTable(tableList) {
        alert('Here : '+tableList);
         var data =new  google.visualization.DataTable(tableList);
         data.addColumn('string', 'CI Name');
         data.addColumn('string', 'Status');
         data.addColumn('string', 'Type Of Ticket');
         data.addColumn('string', 'Sub Area');
         data.addColumn('string', 'Category');
         data.addColumn('string', 'Open Time');
         data.addColumn('string', 'Close Time');
         data.addRow(<c:out value="${data.closeTime}" />);
         var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('detailTable'));

         table.draw(data, {allowHtml: true, showRowNumber: true, width: '200%', height: '100%'});

     }
```

This is the jsp table div

```
<div style="margin-bottom: -20px;" id="bgnone" class="inner bdBGHome">
<label style="font-weight:bold;" >Incident Details</label>
        <div id="detailTable">
```

table is constructing with one row but the result is 7 and the table is not displaying any retrieved contents, Displaying a empty row.

Thanks in advance,

Regards,
Suganth A.

Comment: You're only adding one row. `data.addRow(<c:out value="${data.closeTime}" />);`

Comment: to test am adding one row.but in the table list am getting multiple values as i mentioned in the above as ajax response..